# Put variable in the name of the file to be saved

Tags: r

I write a function to extract and  plot  data from the list. I would like to save the plots under the name which is consist of combination of two variables TS and n_PC. My code is  below. How can I do it?

```
plot_components <- function(WL_1,WL_2,WL_3,WL_4,WL_5,WL_6,WL_7,PC,TS,n_PC) {

TS_comp<- data.frame(reconstructed_ts[[WL_1]][[PC]][[TS]],reconstructed_ts[[WL_2]][[PC]][[TS]],reconstructed_ts[[WL_3]][[PC]][[TS]],reconstructed_ts[[WL_4]][[PC]][[TS]],reconstructed_ts[[WL_5]][[PC]][[TS]],reconstructed_ts[[WL_6]][[PC]][[TS]],reconstructed_ts[[WL_7]][[PC]][[TS]])
names(TS_comp)<-c(as.character(WL_1),as.character(WL_2),as.character(WL_3),as.character(WL_4),as.character(WL_5),as.character(WL_6),as.character(WL_7))


matplot(TS_comp,type="l",xlab="Time",ylab="Reconstructed series",main=as.character(n_PC),lty = "solid")
legend("bottom", 
       legend = (names(TS_comp)),
       col = 1:7,lty = "solid",
       text.col = "black",cex = 0.7, 
       horiz = T,inset = c(0.01, 0.01))

dev.copy(png,'D:/forecast/',file=paste(as.character(TS,n_PC),'.png'))
dev.off()
```

}

Comment: If you struggle to concatenate character vectors in the correct order you should update your question, include those vectors and show expected output. Unclear from questoin what `TS` and `n_PC` is.

Comment: Probably you want `file=paste(TS, n_PC, ".png", sep = "_")` or something like that:  but it really does depend on what `TS` and `n_PC` are.

Comment: difficult to say without a repress example, but a simple solution might be to change `paste` to `paste0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include path argument inside paste

```
dev.copy(png, file=paste0('D:/forecast/',as.character(TS,n_PC),'.png'))
```